# How can I see mutation observers in the developer console?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools, mutation-observers

I think I have some code that might be creating a new mutation observer every time a certain action is performed. I'd like to be able to see whether or not this is the case, but have no idea where they are in the console, or if they're even there at all.

Comment: `The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree.` - they are just another API, so don't exist in some "special" place in the console'

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you show an example? Your suggestion looks interesting!

Comment: Use `debug(MutationObserver)` in devtools console.